# Java custom annotations and documents processor to generate JavaDoc

Tags: java, annotations, documentation-generation

How do I use my custom annotations to automatically create a javadoc?

I have tried to use my IDE intellij to generate a javadoc, but of course it doesnt interact with my custom annotations.
Example code snippet

```
@JavaDoc(
description = "adds two numbers together",
parameters = {"first number","second number"},    
return = {"the sum of the two input numbers}
)

public int pointCoordinat(int a, int b) {
return a + b;
}
```

All I want is for my JavaDoc to contain the text that is written on my custom annotations and I cannot figure out how.

Comment: why do you need the Javadoc inside the annotations at all? Do you need it at runtime? afaik, there is no such tool (or better said, I'm not aware of any), so you'd have to write some Java script by yourself - at least you have access to the annotations, you could produce the HTML docs with it

Answer (score 0):

If you annotate your annotation with `@Documented` your annotation will be included within the generated javadoc. e.g.

```
@Documented
public @interface JavaDoc {
    String description();
}
```

This will not however allow parameters within your annotation be treated like javadoc comment tags, if you need that you'll need to implement something more complex...